# How to export env variables from file in bash script

Tags: bash, export, sh

I need to export a lot of variables like 
export x1=1
export x2=2

I moved all variables in file .env and tried

`source .env`

After it I executed

`printenv`

and all of this variables were absent in the list of env variables.
Also I tried 
`export $(xargs <.env)`
But I have commented lines in .env file and I got following messages

`#': not a valid identifier`

So how can I export variables from file and skip commented lines?

Comment: There is already an answer on the Stack Exchange: [How to export variables from a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79064/how-to-export-variables-from-a-file)

Comment: What exactly does a sample `.env` file that fails look like?

Comment: `source ./.env` worked for me

Answer (score -3):

Try naming a file like variables.env and then try 
        export variables.env
        echo $somevariable_name

Comment: This does not work at all, this just marks the non-existing variable `variables.env` to be exported.